# How to make an italic UILabel without caring about the size?

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont

I have a UILabel, whose `text` or `attributedText` properties I update programatically. Under some cases, I'd like to italicize it. I could either:

A) set the `UILabel.font` property:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize: 12.0];
```

B) or use an attributed string to do something similar:

```
myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"my text" attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize: 12.0]}]]
```

But I don't want to care about the size. I just want the "default" font AND size, but in italic. Currently, I'm actually using the obliqueness attribute:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString: @"My Text"
    attributes: @{NSObliquenessAttributeName: @(0.5)}];
myLabel.attributedText = text;
```

This makes it so I don't have to care about whatever the size is, but I think obliqueness just approximates italics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `[UIFont systemFontSize]`.

```
myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
                     initWithString: @"my text" 
                         attributes: @{
              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize: 
                                         [UIFont systemFontSize]]}]];
```

Moreover, there are few more options to choose from:

```
+ (CGFloat)labelFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for labels.
+ (CGFloat)buttonFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for buttons.
+ (CGFloat)smallSystemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard small system font.
+ (CGFloat)systemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard system font.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to read the point size directly off the labels font.

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:myLabel.font.pointSize];

myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"my text" attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:myLabel.font.pointSize]}];
```